# Pipenv can not load a module

Tags: python, pipenv

I used pipenv to install facebookads, but it is having trouble resolving the AdUser module.

```
import facebookads
from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount 
from facebookads.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights 
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads import adobjects 
from facebookads.adobjects import AdUser

access_token = 'removed from code sample'
ad_account_id = 'removed from code sample'
app_secret = 'removed from code sample'
app_id = 'removed from code sample'
FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id, app_secret, access_token)

# Add after FacebookAdsApi.init
me = AdUser(fbid='me')
my_account = me.get_ad_accounts()[0]
print(my_account)
```

Pycharm shows an error: Unresolved reference: 'AdUser'

The console shows the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/cp/python-scripts/tests-facebook.py", line 11, in <module>
    from facebookads.adobjects import AdUser
ImportError: cannot import name 'AdUser'
```

I've tried an uninstall and reinstall of facebookads SDK. It has not helped.

Another developer suggested a possible problem with the virtual environment.

Any insights on how to fix this would help, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [GitHub thread,](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/issues/345) it seems `AdUser` has been renamed `AdAccountUser`. You could try the import statement

`from facebookads.adobjects.adaccountuser import AdAccountUser`

to fix your issue.

Hope it helps!